# Publish local db to shared hosting

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to publish my Db that is locate in my App data folder,(tables & data)
Since my hosting do not support web deploy I need to create a script file from it, I didn’t find any option to do it .

Using SQl studio M . script to file option i'm getting this error:Index was outside the bounds of the array. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo) ".

Comment: As a workaround, if you have remote access to your DB server, you can use WebDeploy to your local machine and publish the database to your remote DB's connection string.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37528 looks like a feasible solution.